# Recaptcha doesn't display correctly in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, recaptcha

I have included Recaptcha in a form on my site. It works correctly and displays correctly in all browsers except Google Chrome where the theme is broken some how. I suspected it was an issue with the iframe and tried `iframe{display:none;}` but this didn't achieve anything.

Is there another way I can stop the recaptcha theme from breaking?

Link to the recaptcha on my site: [www.melfordschoolofmotoring.co.uk/book.php](http://www.melfordschoolofmotoring.co.uk/book.php)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? The page looks the same in Firefox, Chrome and Safari for me. Do you have any Chrome plugins? Does the site still look broken in Chrome if you view it in "Incognito" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have an Ad Blocker enabled which is getting in the way? Or a filter which is blocking the image? Just suggesting!

Comment: Yeah i looked at it on chrome on my laptop and the theme is intact. Strange. I gather suspect it was a plugin.

Comment: No prob. Had a similar problem a few months ago with an advert not showing.